# Jquery Address Plugin Post issue

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery-address

Hi I am learning to use the Jquery Address plugin, and am using the tutorial over
[here](http://www.thetutorialblog.com/jquery/deep-linking-with-jquery/)

So here is the html

```
<a href="test1.html" rel="address:/test1">Test 1</a><br />
<a href="test2.html" rel="address:/test2">Test 2</a>

Load Area: <br />
<div id="area"></div>
```

And here is the Jquery code

```
function loadURL(url) {
        $("#area").load(url);
    }


    // Event handlers
    $.address.init(function(event))
.change(function(event) {
        $("#area").load($('[rel=address:' + event.value + ']').attr('href'));
    })

    $('a').click(function(){
        loadURL($(this).attr('href'));
    });
```

Now this works well. However I want to do a POST call on the back button. So I replace

```
$("#area").load($('[rel=address:' + event.value + ']').attr('href'));
```

with

```
var myhref = $('[rel=address:' + event.value + ']').attr('href');
$.post(myhref, function(data) {
        $('#area').html(data);
    });
```

This throws the console error "this.value is not a function".

Considering my very superficial knowledge of Jquery (& programming in general), what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Actually it seems that GET is good enough for me. But I would still like to know why I can't do $.post.

Answer (score 0):

Aw man I wish someone could answer this. I've been trying to get this thing to POST for a day now.. It just wants to get everything it seems, but I am at a loss of how I would tweak it to post.

Comment: The plugin author is right, he only provides a API to handle the address hash changes. Some time spent with the documentation solves the problem; I have posted an implementation below, please let me know if it works for you

Comment: I tried your code snip and it does indeed post so I guess that's a start, but it is not actually sending data through post still. I modded your second code block to look like this:     $("form").live("submit",function() {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.address.value($(this).attr("href"));
        $.post($(this).attr("href"), function(data){
            $("#content").html(data);
        });
        console.log('binding to form');
        return false;
    }); as a novice to js I don't know where to go from here. Any help much appreciated! Maybe I should try form plugin?

Comment: okay thanks for the code tip. I have a good handle on it now. It wasn't posting before because I did not realize I had to explicitly define the form data when using .ajax to send.

Comment: Yes, I had omitted the form data part for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

```
function loadURL(url) {
        $.post(url, function(data){
            $("#area").html(data);
        })
    }


    // Event handlers

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("a").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $.address.value($(this).attr("href"));
            $.post($(this).attr("href"), function(data){
                $("#area").html(data);
            })
            return false;
        })
    })

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.address.init(function(event) { // Initates the address plugin
        }).externalChange(function(event) { //externalChange is browser back/fwd button/address bar
            if(event.path != "/"){
                loadURL(event.path);
            }
        })
    })
```